# Ubuntu doesn't remember settings

Tags: display-resolution, settings, xrandr, system-settings, nvidia-settings

I have problem with Linux Mint doesn't remember settings.
The settings I need every time set after loading Linux is display settings (adding resolution to one of displays, and applying this resolution to the display) and max-user-watches and max-user-instances.

Commands I need to run every day:

```
sudo nano /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

*change number in the file*

```
sudo nano /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
```

*change number in the file*

```
xrandr --newmode 1440x900_60.00 106.50 1440 1528 1672 1904 900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP-1 1440x900_60.00
xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 1440x900_60.00
```

That one last command I sometimes run, but usually Linux in some weird way remembers this last setting.

How can I make Mint remember these settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 2 inotify settings you can do as follow and the  by what you need.

```
echo "fs.inotify.max_user_instances = <YOURVALUE>" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.d/20-inotify.conf

echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches = <YOURVALUE>" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.d/20-inotify.conf
```

For the xrandr try the following:

```
echo "xrandr --newmode 1440x900_60.00 106.50 1440 1528 1672 1904 900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync" | sudo tee -a /etc/X11/Xsession.d/51-custom-monitor

echo "xrandr --addmode DP-1 1440x900_60.00" | sudo tee -a /etc/X11/Xsession.d/51-custom-monitor`

echo "xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 1440x900_60.00" | sudo tee -a /etc/X11/Xsession.d/51-custom-monitor`
```

Then check if it's persisted after a reboot.

Comment: Great, it works! However, I have a question. Why exactly you named a file 51-custom-monitor? What sense makes that 51 in the beginning. And do I understand correctly, that inside Xsession.d are kept scripts for xserver?

Comment: I chose 51 so it runs before `55gnome-session_gnomerc`